# Can anyone spot the mistake I made in this proof by induction?

Tags: solution-verification, induction, asymptotics

While understanding big-O notation is important to understanding the statement I'm trying to prove anyone with a strong understanding of induction might be able to identify the mistake I made.

I attempted to complete a proof using induction, but made a mistake somewhere. While the statement I'm trying to prove is correct ($3n^{100}=O(2^n)$), my proof is invalid because I used fallacious constants for $c$ and $n_0$, meaning that the inequality I evaluated in my proof ($3k^{100}\le2^{100}\cdot2^k$ for all $k\ge1$) is flase. Basically, I ended up proving an false statement and don't know why. My proof is below.

Prove $ 3n^{100}=O(2^n)$

Using Induction I will show that $3k^{100}\le2^{100}\cdot2^k$ for all $k\ge1$

*Base Case*: I will show that $3k^{100}\le2^{100}\cdot2^k$ for $k=1$

$$LHS=3(1)^{100}=3\le2^{100}\cdot2^{(1)}=2^{101}=RHS$$

*Induction Hypothesis*: Assume that $3k^{100}\le2^{100}\cdot2^k$ for some $k\ge1$

*Induction Step*: I will show that $3(k+1)^{100}\le2^{100}\cdot2^{k+1}$
$$LHS=3(k+1)^{100}$$
$$\le3(k+k)^{100}=3(2k)^{100}$$
$$=2^{100}\cdot3k^{100}$$
$$\le2^{100}\cdot2^k \text{ (Using Induction Hypothesis)}$$
$$\le2^{100}\cdot2^{k+1}=RHS$$
I completed the proof, but when I double checked my work I found that from $k=3$ to around $k=850$ the expression $3k^{100}$ is actually less than $2^{100}\cdot2^k$. I can't figure out why my proof doesn't work. I know my proof could become valid if I choose a really big number for $c$ or $n_0$, but I'd rather understand where I went wrong than just choose random large constants until something works.

[picture showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMWNp.png)

Comment: I think there are typos in the statements in your induction hypothesis and your induction step. Some $2^{100}$ factor seems to be missing.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Since $k\mapsto k+1$ multiplies $k^{100}$ by $(1+1/k)^{100}\approx e^{100/k}$, you can't use the induction step until $e^{100/k}\lesssim2$, i.e. $k\gtrsim\frac{100}{\ln2}$. This doesn't preclude an inductive proof, but requires its base case to be much bigger than $k=1$. It's far easier to use calculus to find the maximum of $x^ae^{-bx}$ (with $a=100,\,b=\ln2$) for $x>0$, especially if you want to understand how the result generalizes.

Comment: Sometimes, your right side has $2^{100}$; sometimes, it doesn't. That's sloppy, and may be the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $~\displaystyle 3 \times \left[k^{100}\right] \leq 2^{100} \times 2^k.$

Then, as you indicated,

$$3 \times \left[(k+1)^{100}\right] \leq 3 \times \left[(2k)^{100}\right] = 2^{100} \times \left\{ ~3 \times \left[k^{100}\right] ~\right\}. \tag1 $$

Then, using the inductive hypothesis, against the RHS of (1) above, you have that

$$2^{100} \times \left\{ ~3 \times \left[k^{100}\right] ~\right\} \leq 2^{100} \times \left\{ ~2^{100} \times 2^k ~\right\} = 2^{\color{red}{200}} \times 2^k.$$

So, you have proven that

$$\text{If} ~~~~3 \times \left[k^{100}\right] \leq 2^{100} \times 2^k $$

$$\text{Then} ~~~~3 \times \left[(k+1)^{100}\right] \leq 2^{\color{red}{200}} \times 2^k.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you change k to k+1, the left hand side is multiplied by (1+1/k)^100 and the right hand side by 2. You can figure out exactly when the left hand side grows slower, but it definitely does at k=200 or larger.

For big-o you can pick N0 = 200 and c = left hand side / right hand side at k= 200.